# Excel Custom Function across a range of cells - Results in a single cell

Tags: excel, function, csv, excel-formula

I hope someone might be able to help. I am trying to put a csv file together from a very messy spreadsheet. I have written the function below which works fine on a single cell and returns the correct response; Red fill = 'exclude, ' Green fill = '"", '

```
Function CheckColor1(range)
    If range.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
        CheckColor1 = "exclude," & " "
    ElseIf range.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) Then
        CheckColor1 = """" & """, "
    Else
        CheckColor1 = ""
    End If
End Function
```

What I'd like to do is apply this function to a row of data and have the responses from each cell written into a **single** cell as either exclude, or "", .

So based on cell colour, A1 to Z1 would return a single cell written as; exclude, exclude, "", exclude, "", and so on.

I hope this makes sense and that someone might be able to help.

Many thanks
D

Comment: You will need to loop the `range` and concatenate each part.

Comment: Do you need to return multiple values? What happens if your range contains different colors?

Comment: @Tarik no it's cool only has 2 values Red, Green or blank. BigBen nailed it worked a treat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop the range:

```vb
Function CheckColor1(ByVal inputRange As Range) As String
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In inputRange
        Dim temp As String

        If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
            temp = "exclude," & " "
        ElseIf cell.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) Then
            temp = """" & """, "
        Else
            temp = ""
        End If

        CheckColor1 = CheckColor1 & temp
   Next
End Function
```